# replace conditional to polymorphism when using typescript model class

Tags: angular, typescript, polymorphism

I have built a game of life simulation and now I am trying to clean the code and make it more Object Orientated. Despite several days of search, I am having a hard time replacing conditionals with polymorphism.

So I have a component.ts a game model and a cell model. The cell model contains property `status: boolean` amongst other things. which can be dead or alive. Then I have given the user the ability to toggle a cell status on start. So I have tried for the status to create an abstract class and then two subclasses with dead or alive but I am not sure if that is the right way to go.

this is the cell.model

```
import { Coordinates } from './coordinates.model';

export class Cell {
  private coordinates: Coordinates;
  public status: string;


  constructor(coordinates) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
    this.status = new Alive().status;
  }

  getCoordinates(): Coordinates {
    return this.coordinates;
  }

  toggleCell(): void {
    console.log(this.status)
  }

}

export abstract class Status {
  status: string;
  abstract setStatus(): string;
}

export class Alive extends Status {
  status = 'alive';
  setStatus(): string {
    return this.status = 'dead';
  }
}

export class Dead extends Status {
  status = 'dead';
  setStatus(): string {
    return this.status = 'alive';
  }
}
```

In the game model as u can see below, I used conditionals to change the status

```
toggleCell(cellIndex: number) {
  const cell: Cell = this.cells[cellIndex];
  // if (this.cells[cellIndex].status === 'dead') {
  //     this.cells[cellIndex].status = 'alive';
  //     this.addToLivingCells(cellIndex);

  // } else {
  //     this.cells[cellIndex].status = 'dead';
  //     this.removeFromLivingCells(cellIndex);
  // }

  cell.toggleCell()
}
```

so what I want to do is remove the conditionals and use polymorphism to toggle the status from the dead to alive and back depending on the current status.

Let me know if the rest of the code is needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Haven't really seen that pattern being used in Angular/TypeScript. Why do you think it is a better approach than using conditionals?

Comment: @SiddAjmera,  I think it is for improved extensibility/reusablity and testing, but not to sure as to specific benefit. But i Typescript is OOP so shouldnt it be possible to apply that here is as well? That is why i couldnt find a single answer on the net around it i guess. most examples show you how to create the classes, but they dont show how you would actually call it from you code. In this case the togglefunction

Answer (score 0):

I think your approuch is too much complicated for such a simple case. For this case this code is enough:

```
export class Cell {
    private coordinates: Coordinates;
    public status: 'alive' | 'dead';

    constructor(coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.status = 'alive';
    }

    getCoordinates(): Coordinates {
        return this.coordinates;
    }

    toggleCell(): void {
        this.status = this.status === 'alive' ? 'dead' : 'alive';
        console.log(this.status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example here does seem too simple to bother with polymorphism... that would probably only be worth it if you find yourself doing a lot of `switch (this.status)` or the like.  But here's how I might go about it:

First, I would make `Status` an interface instead of an abstract class, unless you actually have some common functionality:

```
interface Status {
  readonly status: "alive" | "dead";
  getOtherStatus(): Status;  // instead of setStatus()
  otherFunctionalityThatChangesDependingOnStatus(): void; // etc
}
```

Then, if you do have two classes `Alive` and `Dead`, you absolutely do not want to mutate the `status` string inside `setStatus()`, since that breaks your model entirely.  Because `Alive` and `Dead` are two different classes, an instance of one cannot become an instance of the other (well, it [*technically can*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf), but you shouldn't try to do that).  And since an `Alive` instance must always be an `Alive` instance, it makes little sense to change `this.status` to `"dead"`.  In your original implementation, `const a = new Alive()` is alive, then `a.setStatus()` makes it a "dead `Alive`", and then `a.setStatus()` will keep it a "dead `Alive`", because of the implementation of `Alive.setStatus()`.

Instead, you should treat `Alive` and `Dead` instances as [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), at least as far as their status is concerned.  Instead of mutating `this.status` via `setStatus()`, you should *return* a `Status` object corresponding to the other status via `getOtherStatus()`.  If `Alive` and `Dead` are immutable, there's no real reason to carry around more than one instance of each class (since `const a = new Alive()` and `const b = new Alive()` would make two distinct objects which act exactly the same in all circumstances).  So you can do something like this:

```
class Alive implements Status {
  static readonly instance = new Alive(); // the one instance of Alive
  private constructor() {}
  readonly status = "alive";
  getOtherStatus() {
    return Dead.instance;
  }
  otherFunctionalityThatChangesDependingOnStatus() {
    console.log("It's good to be alive!");       
  }
}

class Dead implements Status {
  static readonly instance = new Dead(); // the one instance of Dead
  private constuctor() {}
  readonly status = "dead";
  getOtherStatus() {
    return Alive.instance;
  }
  otherFunctionalityThatChangesDependingOnStatus() {
    console.log("I'm out of here!")
  }
}
```

So you never call `new Alive()` or `new Dead()`; instead you can grab `Alive.instance` or `Dead.instance`.  Finally you can make `Cell` depend on `Status`. The `status` property of `Cell` should be a `Status` instance, not a string.  That's how you can get the object-oriented behavior of `Alive` and `Dead`.  You initialize `status` to `Alive.instance`, and you `toggleCell()` by setting `this.status` to `this.status.getOtherStatus()`:

```
class Cell {
  private coordinates: Coordinates;
  public status: Status;

  constructor(coordinates: Coordinates) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
    this.status = Alive.instance;
  }

  getCoordinates(): Coordinates {
    return this.coordinates;
  }

  toggleCell(): void {
    this.status = this.status.getOtherStatus();
    console.log(this.status);
  }
}
```

And let's test it:

```
const c = new Cell(null!);
c.status.otherFunctionalityThatChangesDependingOnStatus(); // It's good to be alive!
c.toggleCell();
c.status.otherFunctionalityThatChangesDependingOnStatus(); // I'm out of here!
c.toggleCell();
c.status.otherFunctionalityThatChangesDependingOnStatus(); // It's good to be alive!
```

Looks good.  Okay, hope this helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjmArgZ2QbwChlkoI4ATAexABsBPZHDbHALmQCI5bgA3CJ2QAfLhXIVOAbmLIA5hDAB5MAAto6TLgAUASg6bWMklTXQAYlhAIwwGj2Bh6AFVWYAwm5AKcAEQgADhAgFKBySiCGOvrIfFTAFDIAvoSECLRwOHgAgrwCyMAAtgG0EIXBYHhReEQkzJjACKQSNAwFIPXWKAC8yCAQAO7IufwQesbIAVD8mCgINMxQWDZUUHoEKSRklK2M9azIvdx5ghMKymZQ1eu1JM3YUCDI-pQAdKCdSBObyKbqUJZrLZ7LwnK4PF4fP4giEwhFrroCLISPMOlRSq9aFQ5NpOABJMAAcjwcioVAoyDAVGQACMUA4BABCTi6b6EFJpDJZZ4SArFUrlcBVFi4JF1FiNZo7OiMD4YLqHPqDHmUcayKYzSDIVHMZZUtaI-A-bbUGVMEV4I7iSjSWTnFT-BFiu5kB5PEYCd4deVfWQ-P4WKw2OwgBxgtxgTxwbwQPyBYKhbzwi03ZHahboiCY7G4vGEwq-LBgX4wZD-CDM1l+9mpdKZPDuCC0WjOjV8Wbp1aJ2bsZDuMlQbuQHATAJYGm8Jr7XAGC0yWQ6sBLFZreZd0A9jj99eh4eGtNqYA4V5rwcb4eK09D2MTEiH4-Ty3DE5ez4QNl2xTbs+72N6LcDteNRpq6WCPJSqhHiegHnje1ayFSchyKUjbNv+sTxBStx3pBD4Woq96vI+rz2pcCK3umaIYliOKEY+VYkCkHKLtqir9EMqG0NoIBYM2jJVggREWq8AYAkGwKhqCLgRlGMZxjCibhJEKassgAD0anIASxLyGSFJUrS9InIyaSvIhyEQJxaqCcRomAsGIKONJELRlC8awkmylaDg4zqZpeYFlQRYlmW0AVqZ5koU2XECUJ3kiZc9kSWGzmRpCsbQgmcJeawvkaVpRIknplLUnSyAMuFQA)